# prevent TextField that are dynamic in nature from getting autofilled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

TextFields in my form are dynamically added based on an array of items(which is a state variable), after filling in the TextField, on click of a "SET VALUE" button , I would be removing the filled textfield.

The value entered in the removed textfield is getting autofilled to its successive textfield, I couldn,t find a way to prevent this behaviour.

Please find the [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dqc1c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are using index as a key. 
From react docs:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
>   change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
>   with component state.

And that's exactly what is happening in your app. 
You can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) to read more. 
Instead of:

```
<Grid item key={index}>
```

You can use

```
<Grid item key={item}>
```

That is in case every element in the array is (and will be) unique. 
If that's not the case, you should think of other key.

Answer (score 0):

Add `key` to your `TextField`. Something like -

`<TextField key={Math.random()}> </TextField>`

or

`<TextField key={item}> </TextField>` and it will fix your problem.